# Joomla 2.5 ordering sidebar menu alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have tried looking everywhere, but can't find a right direction from where to start. 
Actually I have inserted menus in joomla menus from component using mysql trigger. Menus are built nicely, but now I want to arrange them alphabetically for parent and child for example:

```
Agriculture
  Fetilizers
  Pesticides 
  Pump sets
Electronics
  DVD Player
  Microwave 
  Television
```

Thanks.

Comment: if your creating them via SQL query , just order the query ASC or DESC

Comment: No I have inserted in the default joomla #__menu table using trigger. I can't from where the ordering is controlled.

Comment: There is a column called "ordering" that seems to control that for each menutype.

Comment: @gregory - No It seem it is redundant now, any changes to that column has no effect.

Comment: Well if it's 2.5 the column is used when you change the order in the admin panel. If t has no effect in your changes I'd look for constraints on other colums values, especially parent and sublevel that seem related to this. A simple 1 level menu would have parent = 0, sublevel = 0 and ordering 1 to n as expected.

Comment: You need to do it manually with drag and drop ordering.  You may prefer to use the categories module which should have an option for this (didn't check). There is also a default setting in content for how to sort categories and articles.